# How can I configure dnsmasq to resolve based on the source of the request?

Tags: dns, routing, proxy, dnsmasq

I'm trying to get [SiriProxy](https://github.com/plamoni/SiriProxy) to work whenever I'm connected to my home network by setting up dnsmasq on my router running the Tomato firmware to send all requests to the Apple Siri server to my local machine running SiriProxy.

The problem is, of course, that the machine running SiriProxy needs to access the "real" Apple Siri server. I don't know how often it changes IP addresses, so the simple solution would just be to point it at the IP address...

However, is there a way to configure DNSMasq so it will only obey the "address" configuration option when the request is (or is not) coming from certain clients?

Alternatively.. does anyone have a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use iptables, you can route all requests to Siri via the SiriProxy.  I use the following command to route certain sites via a Proxy server and the rest is routed directly to my ISP:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport $destination_port -d $destination_ip_address -j DNAT --to-destination $Proxyserver:port
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems like the ideal way to do it transparently. I ended up explicitly setting the DNS server on the machine running SiriProxy